# Setting a timeout for ServerXMLHTTP request

Tags: asp-classic, timeout, javascript, serverxmlhttp

Does anyone know how to set up set up a default action for when a ServerXMLHTTP request times out?  I'm using setTimeouts() to set the time out options according to the [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760403%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Ideally I would like to initialize the request again from the beginning or refresh the page should it time out.

I'm using classic asp and jscript.

Here's my request:

```
function serverXmlHttp(url) {
    var serverXmlHttp;
    serverXmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0");

    // set time out options
    serverXmlHttp.setTimeouts(15000,15000,15000,15000);

    // does not work
    // serverXmlHttp.ontimeout(Response.Write("page has timed out"));

    serverXmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
    serverXmlHttp.send();

    if (serverXmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        return serverXmlHttp.responseText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. I just need to use a try/catch statement.

```
function serverXmlHttp(url) {

    try {
        var serverXmlHttp;
        serverXmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0");

        // set time out options
        serverXmlHttp.setTimeouts(15000,15000,15000,15000);

        serverXmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
        serverXmlHttp.send();

        if (serverXmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            return serverXmlHttp.responseText;
        }
    catch(error) {
        // whatever I want to happen if there's an error
        Response.Write("Sorry, your request has timed out");
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are using pure Classic ASP, you can catch the `msxml6.dll` error `80072EE2` (“The operation timed out”). It’ll be thrown by the `send` method.

Answer (score 5):

The important thing is to find out why it is timing out ..

Is the remote Url on the same application as the calling page ?

if so have a look at **[INFO: Do Not Send ServerXMLHTTP or WinHTTP Requests to the Same Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316451)** as you will be facing thread starvation ..

Comment: No, it is not.  The request is being made to a database on another server. I just want to have a fail safe in case the request does time out (as it has done on occasion) rather than a generic time out error.